# My Sql stored preceedure is not working expectedly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to code stored preceedure to manage leaves of a company as leaves should be credited periodically to each employee. I am using tables

```
erp_leave_policy => Describing Leave policy, 
erp_employees    => Describing Employees, 
erp_clients      => Describing Employees are belonged to which Client, 
erp_employee_leave_policy => Describing leave policy of employees.
```

I am using the following query with my stored procedure

```
SELECT lpc_id,emp_id  FROM erp_leave_policy,erp_employees,erp_clients,erp_employee_leave_policy 
                WHERE emp_status=1 AND cli_status=1 AND lpc_status=1 AND 
                emp_id = elp_fk_employees AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;
```

And it is working fine with no issues.

[image: Click here to see output]

But in my stored procedure, this query is not working. I am using codeigniter. My code is as follows.

```
$this->db->query("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS inserter;");
$q = "  CREATE FUNCTION inserter(emp_id bigint,lpc_id int) RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN

            INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_lpc_id,aaa_emp_id) VALUES (lpc_id, emp_id);   

             RETURN 1;
            END;";

$this->db->query($q);
$this->db->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS start_credit_test;");
$q = " CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test()
        BEGIN
            DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;


            DEClARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR 

            SELECT lpc_id,emp_id  FROM erp_leave_policy,erp_employees,erp_clients,erp_employee_leave_policy 
            WHERE emp_status=1 AND cli_status=1 AND lpc_status=1 AND 
            emp_id = elp_fk_employees AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;

            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
                   FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

            OPEN emp_cursor;

                get_emp: LOOP

                    FETCH emp_cursor INTO lpc_id,emp_id;

                    IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                    LEAVE get_emp;
                    END IF;

                    inserter(emp_id,lpc_id);

                END LOOP get_emp;

            CLOSE emp_cursor;

           END ";


$this->db->query($q);

$query = $this->db->query("CALL start_credit_test();");
```

The error is as follows

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(emp_id,lpc_id); END LOOP get_emp; CLO' at line 27

CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test() BEGIN DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0; DECLARE lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0; DECLARE emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0; DEClARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT lpc_id,emp_id FROM erp_leave_policy,erp_employees,erp_clients,erp_employee_leave_policy WHERE emp_status=1 AND cli_status=1 AND lpc_status=1 AND emp_id = elp_fk_employees AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients; DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1; OPEN emp_cursor; get_emp: LOOP FETCH emp_cursor INTO lpc_id,emp_id; IF v_finished = 1 THEN LEAVE get_emp; END IF; inserter(emp_id,lpc_id); END LOOP get_emp; CLOSE emp_cursor; END
```

I tried this code without calling the function inserter() by replacing `inserter(emp_id,lpc_id);` with

```
INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_lpc_id,aaa_emp_id) VALUES (lpc_id, emp_id);
```

Now it is not displaying errors. But nothing was inserted to table aaa_test. 
Also when use the `DELIMITER //` before `CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test()` and when I call `$this->db->query()`, It will also showing error. For example

```
$q = " DELIMITER //
        CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test()
        BEGIN
         .........
        .............";
 $this->db->query($q);
```

The error as follows

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test() BEGI' at line 1
```

So can you please help

Comment: A function must be part of a select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everybody.
I corrected my code as you suggested. And changed the name of the variables I declared with the stored procedure. That is I changed
    `DECLARE lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;`
As
    `DECLARE my_lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE my_emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;`
And then I changed
    `call inserter(emp_id,lpc_id);`
As
    `INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_emp_id,aaa_lpc_id) VALUES (my_emp_id,my_lpc_id);`

Now My Total code is as

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_finished INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE my_lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE my_emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;


    DEClARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR 

    SELECT lpc_id,emp_id  FROM erp_leave_policy,erp_employees,erp_clients,erp_employee_leave_policy 
            WHERE emp_status=1 AND cli_status=1 AND lpc_status=1 AND 
            emp_id = elp_fk_employees AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN emp_cursor;

        get_emp: LOOP

            FETCH emp_cursor INTO my_lpc_id,my_emp_id;

            IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_emp;
            END IF;

            INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_emp_id,aaa_lpc_id) VALUES (my_emp_id,my_lpc_id);  

        END LOOP get_emp;

    CLOSE emp_cursor;

    END$$;
    DELIMITER ;
```

It will insert values to table aaa_test as 
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvOcE.png)

But when I calling the function inserter, It is getting again error

```
PROCEDURE abn_erp.inserter does not exist
```

I am putting my entire code below

```
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS inserter;

            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE FUNCTION inserter(emp_id bigint, lpc_id int) RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_emp_id,aaa_lpc_id) VALUES (emp_id,lpc_id);   

                RETURN 1;
            END $$;
            DELIMITER ;


            DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS start_credit_test;

            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test()
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE v_finished INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
                    DECLARE my_lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
                    DECLARE my_emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;


                    DEClARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR 

                    SELECT lpc_id,emp_id  FROM erp_leave_policy,erp_employees,erp_clients,erp_employee_leave_policy 
                            WHERE emp_status=1 AND cli_status=1 AND lpc_status=1 AND 
                            emp_id = elp_fk_employees AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;

                    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

                    OPEN emp_cursor;

                        get_emp: LOOP

                            FETCH emp_cursor INTO my_lpc_id,my_emp_id;

                            IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                            LEAVE get_emp;
                            END IF;

                             call inserter(my_emp_id,my_lpc_id);  

                        END LOOP get_emp;

                    CLOSE emp_cursor;

                    END $$;
                    DELIMITER ;
```

But when I calling start_credit_test() as 
`$this->db->query("CALL start_credit_test();")`
getting error as `PROCEDURE abn_erp.inserter does not exist`

Comment: Sagar Gangwal solved the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502307/getting-errors-when-calling-functions-inside-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue about delimiter

```
$q = " DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;


        DEClARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR 

        SELECT lpc_id,emp_id  FROM erp_leave_policy,erp_employees,erp_clients,erp_employee_leave_policy 
        WHERE emp_status=1 AND cli_status=1 AND lpc_status=1 AND 
        emp_id = elp_fk_employees AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
               FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

        OPEN emp_cursor;

            get_emp: LOOP

                FETCH emp_cursor INTO lpc_id,emp_id;

                IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE get_emp;
                END IF;

                inserter(emp_id,lpc_id);

            END LOOP get_emp;

        CLOSE emp_cursor;

        END$$
        DELIMITER ; ";
```

Comment: It is getting error when running in codeigniter as `$this->db->query($q)` . The error is as follows: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test() BEGIN DECLARE v' at line 1`. But when running this in PhpMyAdmin there is no errors. But nothing inserted to the table `aaa_test`

Comment: The code is running in phpMyadmin of WAMP. But when using codeigniter `$this->db->querry($q)`, it is showing the error that I commented above. But to run in phpMyadmin I changed something. `inserter(emp_id,lpc_id);` as `call inserter(emp_id,lpc_id);` and `END$$` as `END$$;`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error near the `inserter` procedure calling, you should use CALL command -

```
...
CALL inserter(emp_id,lpc_id);
...
```

Another one, I think you can **simplify** your task:

1. Use just one stored procedure, or even just one statement -
2. Avoid cursor using

There is an [INSERT...SELECT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) which inserts records from another data set in one command, for example -

```
INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_lpc_id, aaa_emp_id)
  SELECT
    lpc_id,
    emp_id
  FROM erp_leave_policy,
       erp_employees,
       erp_clients,
       erp_employee_leave_policy
  WHERE emp_status = 1
  AND cli_status = 1
  AND lpc_status = 1
  AND emp_id = elp_fk_employees
  AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy
  AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;
```

Comment: Ok, When I used `CALL inserter(emp_id,lpc_id);` the error was removed. But nothing was inserted to the table `aaa_test` when run my query (Not the query you suggested . Because my need is not inserting anything to table `aaa_test`. It is just for an example. There are some more processes to do in this stored proceedure.

Comment: The SELECT must return records. Check it. I'd suggest to use INSERT...SELECT statement.

Comment: If you want to check the problem with procedure, you can debug it with our mysql debugger - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html#header. Trial version.

Answer (score 0):

errors may be contained on : `DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;`

change to : `DECLARE v_finished INT(11) DEFAULT 0;`

Comment: There is no changes found in result