# Getting errors when calling functions inside stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am writing a stored procedure to manage leaves of employees in a company. Leave should be credited to each employee periodically.

My code is as follows

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS inserter;

DELIMITER $$;
CREATE FUNCTION inserter(emp_id bigint, lpc_id int) RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_emp_id,aaa_lpc_id) 
    VALUES (emp_id,lpc_id);   

    RETURN 1;
END $$;
DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS start_credit_test;

DELIMITER $$;

CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_finished INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE my_lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE my_emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT lpc_id, emp_id  
        FROM erp_leave_policy, erp_employees, erp_clients, erp_employee_leave_policy 
        WHERE emp_status = 1 
          AND cli_status = 1 
          AND lpc_status = 1 
          AND emp_id = elp_fk_employees 
          AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy 
          AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN emp_cursor;

    get_emp: LOOP

        FETCH emp_cursor INTO my_lpc_id,my_emp_id;

        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_emp;
        END IF;

        call inserter(my_emp_id,my_lpc_id);  

   END LOOP get_emp;

   CLOSE emp_cursor;

END $$;
DELIMITER ;
```

I am using codeigniter. Then when I do

```
$this->db->query("CALL start_credit_test();");
```

I'm getting an error:

> PROCEDURE abn_erp.inserter does not exist

The query inside the procedure

```
SELECT lpc_id, emp_id  
FROM erp_leave_policy, erp_employees, erp_clients, erp_employee_leave_policy 
WHERE emp_status = 1 
  AND cli_status = 1 
  AND lpc_status = 1 
  AND emp_id = elp_fk_employees 
  AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy 
  AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;
```

returns the output:

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzkyV.png)

Then I inserted function again as

```
            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE FUNCTION inserter(emp_id bigint, lpc_id int) RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_emp_id,aaa_lpc_id) VALUES (emp_id,lpc_id);   

                RETURN 1;
            END $$;
            DELIMITER ;
```

But it shows the error `#1304 - FUNCTION inserter already exists`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Not as nice to read, with `WHERE` clauses it will run it as an `INNER JOIN` anyway, however without it will do a (Cartesian) `CROSS JOIN`... I personally rather the usage of explicit join syntax however if doing in in a `FROM` was so bad, it would have been properly deprecated  by now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please rename it with `inseterLeave` as shown below.

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE FUNCTION inseterLeave (emp_id bigint, lpc_id int) RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO aaa_test (aaa_emp_id,aaa_lpc_id) VALUES (emp_id,lpc_id);   
    RETURN 1;
END $$;
DELIMITER ;
```

and rewrite procedure with below code.

You did not need `call` keyword to `call function` from `procedure`.I had made changes according to it.

```
       DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS start_credit_test;

            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE PROCEDURE start_credit_test()
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE v_finished INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
                    DECLARE my_lpc_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
                    DECLARE my_emp_id BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;


                    DEClARE emp_cursor CURSOR FOR 

                    SELECT lpc_id,emp_id  FROM erp_leave_policy,erp_employees,erp_clients,erp_employee_leave_policy 
                            WHERE emp_status=1 AND cli_status=1 AND lpc_status=1 AND 
                            emp_id = elp_fk_employees AND lpc_id = elp_fk_leave_policy AND cli_id = emp_fk_clients;

                    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

                    OPEN emp_cursor;

                        get_emp: LOOP

                            FETCH emp_cursor INTO my_lpc_id,my_emp_id;

                            IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                            LEAVE get_emp;
                            END IF;
 SELECT inseterLeave(my_emp_id,my_lpc_id) FROM DUAL; <-- Please remove call keyword from this line.Function did not require call keyword!>


                        END LOOP get_emp;

                    CLOSE emp_cursor;

                    END $$;
                    DELIMITER ;
```

I think `inseter` is inbuilt `function`or `Function` with same name `already exist`.Hope this will helps you.

Comment: It is OK. but what is mean by DUAL. Is it the name of a temporary table or any special meaningful keyword ?

Comment: it's just special one row by default present in all schema of `MySQL`.`DUAL` can be accessed by every user.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much